# Cannot call `data` because a callable signature is missing in `TestObject` [1]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I am trying to declare the type of a function that can take function or object as a parameter, but the result is `` Cannot call `data` because a callable signature is missing in `TestObject` [1]. ``

This is basic code example what I trying to achieve.

```
type TestObject = {
  name: string
}

const dummyFunction = (data: TestObject | (props:Object)=> TestObject) => {
  typeof data === 'function' ? props => data(props): data;

  return {} // empty object just for the test purpose
}
```

or link to [flow-type](https://flow.org/try/#0FDAuE8AcFMAIBVoGdQHkBGAraBjUsBeWAb2FnIDsBDAW2gC5YUAnASwoHNgBfEHAewopYAEwCuNGuABiYinlaDCsABQiqoKo0QoM2PLAA+qyM36Qk9PblABKAgD4EyNFhu3CT0uQgx+AM1ENKkICIgByfzkFQXDYAH5YU3MkTyDNFWSLD0Z1TR5YIA)

What I am missed?

Comment: Shouldn't your ternary operator be `typeof data === 'function' ? data : () => data` if you're trying to normalize it to a function? `data(props)` is the issue, because in that part of the ternary, `data` is an object and not a function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you, I fixed it but the issue is still there.

Comment: Before I answer the question, what exactly is the return type supposed to be?

Comment: It always should be `Object`, this is just a simplified example of my function. 
But basically, my function should take Object or function as a parameter and return will always `Object`.

Comment: `props => data(props)` is a function...

Comment: Sure it is right, but I don't return `props => data(props)` there as you can see. I didn't return anything there. So let's say on the end I will add `return {}`.

Comment: But `props => data(props)` doesn't _do_ anything. You create a function that is never executed or returned. And since that bit is exactly what giving you the error, it'll help to know what you're trying to do there.

Comment: By the way, the issue is that your `TestObject` type isn't mutually exclusive with a function, so the `data === 'function'` isn't enough to determine that you're _not_ dealing with a `TestObject`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you, I will try to determine it a different way.

Comment: I still don't know where is the problem.  But this solution works for me 
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqeAzhgPIBGAVngMYZgC8YA3qmGAHYCGAtngBcYMgCcAllwDmqAL7o6cLmTAATAK58+WAGLquDcUuZgAFKp4Yew4mSq0GYAD5mcouDhLD79DAEpmAD4iUgoaXwCmYPZOcShTbHw4KDVLHjAAQiYWAHIofUMlHICYzjBRPAx1US5UqwBuDjB5TkVlRgsrPQMMI1qWU3M04R4uLD9hUzcPLzAfBkjg2zCHfyaKqpqwac8gup5uwq4p908-RvlUNpUMUIBGEw0tXQLepVNWbn4hMByAC3EOWaflQwGAYGujFuZAATI9NNpDm9jp8oOJRGQAHLfYT-QHAq5KG6hADM8OeSL6g14AkWZk+NIIsj8IMhYGhGAALOTEa8qaZGXSPmA0RiMNiBMJGcC-EA